# Regex, Match uppercase characters not between brackets

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

In RegEx, I search a pattern that selects multiple uppercase characters (more than 1), that are not enclosed by curly braces.

It should match:

```
ABC
AB
XYZABC
```

but not:

```
{ABC}
{AB}
{XYZABC}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match one or more uppercase letters only if it is not followed by a closing curly `}` bracket.

```
^[A-Z]+(?!.*?})$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jK4iZ4/1)

**OR**

You could use perl regex verbs,

```
{.*?}(*SKIP)(*F)|[A-Z]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jK4iZ4/2)

Comment: character class must be [A-Z] and not [A-z]

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern

```
[A-Z]+(?![^}{]*})
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aU7wA9/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
{.*?}|([A-Z]+)
```

Then test group1 if not empty

[Demo](http://rubular.com/r/MjfaTzYYuT)