# Regex match characters not between delimiters in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, csv

The regex code `[0-9](?=[^\{]*\})` will match only each numeral between braces:

> a1b2c3 [d4e5f6] {g**7**h**8**i**9**}

I'm looking for a code which will match only the numerals *outside* the braces.

> a**1**b**2**c**3** [d**4**e**5**f**6**] {g7h8i9}

A similar question was asked here: [Regex, Match uppercase characters not between brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711903/regex-match-uppercase-characters-not-between-brackets). But the answers give an "Invalid Regular Expression" error in Notepad++

Comment: If you need to remove the numbers, you can match and capture the braces and just match the digits. Like [`(\{[^}]*\})|\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/hV2kH1/2) and replace with `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this negative lookahead regex:

```
[0-9]+(?![^{}]*})
```

`(?![^{}]*})` is negative lookahead to assert that matching numbers are not inside `{...}`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qT6fF1/1)

Comment: [0-9]+ finds a block of numerals. Use [0-9] for individual numerals. The open and closing braces need to be escaped into, to be treated as literal characters, giving (?![^\{}]*\}). I'm not sure what the first closebrace does, but the code works without it, giving [0-9](?![^\{]*\})

Comment: Inside `[...]` all special metachars don't need to be escaped

Comment: A slightly simpler solution, for N++ flavour: `[0-9](?![0-9]*\})`. Any numeral character _not_ followed by zero or more other numerals, then not followed by a literal closebrace, is matched. Any sequence of numerals followed by a closebrace is excluded. Would be more robust with a positive lookbehind for any sequence starting with an openbrace.

Comment: [When do I need to escape characters within a regex character set (within \[\])?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593387/when-do-i-need-to-escape-characters-within-a-regex-character-set-within)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  working as a charm..

Find what: `\d|(\[.*\})`
Replace with: `$1`

Below picture is for what I have captured with regex
And it's example and it's Results or outputs,
Regards.
[image]